# Events - upload image

Tags: wordpress, civievent, images

Has anyone come across a plugin/extension/hook that adds an upload image ability to events "Info and Settings" tab (or a separate tab)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there anything stopping you using Custom Fields to do this? Thats normally how people add extra information they wish to hold about the event. You'd then need to do some work on the display side to use the image.

Comment: And use the custom fields in a Profile? Can you use profiles on the event info page? I think you can only use them on the event reg page.
I have overloaded already i think this is the only way on the event info page.

Comment: No you couldn't use them in a profile as you cant create events in a profile. But if you were trying to record attendees then you could create them against participants and then use them in profiles.